# phpMyID configuration problems

Tags: openid, openid-provider, openid-selector

I have followed the instructions on the read me file and everything seems to be working but when I try to use my own domain address as my OpenID for stackoverflow, I get this error message:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

**UPDATE:** So I tried to solve the problem on my own and I am not getting any errors now. What happens, however, is that I go from the stackoverflow page to my domain name page and never return.

Comment: I have an idea: something's wrong. Sorry, but this error message tells us nothing. You have to find some site that will give a more detailed error ( http://test-id.org/ perhaps? ). Or provide the domain name, so I can test it myself.

Comment: lol, I supposed that the "while sending a direct message or getting the response" would help. The website is http://www.sebkom.me/ and I login from http://www.sebkom.me/MyID.config.php. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, what looks wrong now is that I am not redirected back?

Comment: The second link that you've provided doesn't work (404). Anyay, if it doesn't return, it means that you've probably broken something and the provider doesn't work at all anymore.

Comment: It's because the link is now sebkom.me/index.php instead. I can access it and login properly, I just can't use the url as my openid in other websites. Thanks for offering to help anyway.

Comment: While I can't login to your site, it seems to work properly when canceling the request. If you'd change the login data to test/test for example, I could test logging in. By the way, I assume that you're using `http://www.sebkom.me/index.php` as your openid (`sebkom.me` won't work here, you have broken delegation).

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use /index.php but are you saying there is a way to use sebkom.me instead? Changed the credentials by the way, you should be able to login now.

Answer (score 1):

phpMyID is an OpenId 1.0 provider, and stackoverflow seems to have some kind of problem with it. Your solution would be to login twice, and it will work (I've checked that it works, and the problem isn't limited to phpMyID).

You might want to test my [new provider library](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/trees/master/provider) that uses OpenID 2.0, avoiding this problem.

You have asked if it's possible to use `sebkom.me` as the openid url -- it is.
For phpMyID, add:

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://sebkom.me/index.php">
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://sebkom.me/index.php">
```

For my library just invoke `$op->server();` before any output (see `example.php`). If you decide to test my library, just ask me directly with any questions.